# Segmentation fault when using redisAsyncCommand()

Tags: c, redis

i have next simple code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <signal.h>
    #include "hiredis.h"
    #include "async.h"
    #include "adapters/libevent.h"

void onMessage(redisAsyncContext *c, void *reply, void *privdata) {
    redisReply *r = reply;
    if (reply == NULL) return;

    int j;

    if (r->type == REDIS_REPLY_ARRAY) {
        for (j = 0; j < r->elements; j++) {
            printf("%u) %s\n", j, r->element[j]->str);
        }
    }*/
}


int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
    struct event_base *base = event_base_new();

    redisAsyncContext *c = redisAsyncConnect("127.0.0.1", 6379);
    if (c->err) {
        printf("error: %s\n", c->errstr);
        return 1;
    }

    redisLibeventAttach(c, base);
    redisAsyncCommand(c, onMessage, NULL, "SUBSCRIBE messages");
    event_base_dispatch(base);
    return 0;
}
```

program compiles and runs well. but it returns error "Segmentation fault" when executes. if i comment redisAsyncCommand() function error disappears.
where is the error in my code?

added:

when i compile my code i have warnings:

```
make all 
'Building file: ../src/redis.c'
'Invoking: Cross GCC Compiler'
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -I"C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include" -I"C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\hiredis" -I"C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\event2" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/redis.d" -MT"src/redis.o" -o "src/redis.o" "../src/redis.c"
In file included from ../src/redis.c:7:0:
C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\hiredis/adapters/libevent.h: In function 'redisLibeventAddRead':
C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\hiredis/adapters/libevent.h:56:15: warning: passing argument 1 of 'event_add' from incompatible pointer type
     event_add(&e->rev,NULL);
               ^
In file included from C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\hiredis/adapters/libevent.h:33:0,
                 from ../src/redis.c:7:
C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\event2/event.h:937:5: note: expected 'struct event *' but argument is of type 'struct event **'
 int event_add(struct event *ev, const struct timeval *timeout);
     ^
In file included from ../src/redis.c:7:0:
C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\hiredis/adapters/libevent.h: In function 'redisLibeventDelRead':
C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\hiredis/adapters/libevent.h:61:15: warning: passing argument 1 of 'event_del' from incompatible pointer type
     event_del(&e->rev);
               ^
In file included from C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\hiredis/adapters/libevent.h:33:0,
                 from ../src/redis.c:7:
C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\event2/event.h:950:5: note: expected 'struct event *' but argument is of type 'struct event **'
 int event_del(struct event *);
     ^
In file included from ../src/redis.c:7:0:
C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\hiredis/adapters/libevent.h: In function 'redisLibeventAddWrite':
C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\hiredis/adapters/libevent.h:66:15: warning: passing argument 1 of 'event_add' from incompatible pointer type
     event_add(&e->wev,NULL);
               ^
In file included from C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\hiredis/adapters/libevent.h:33:0,
                 from ../src/redis.c:7:
C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\event2/event.h:937:5: note: expected 'struct event *' but argument is of type 'struct event **'
 int event_add(struct event *ev, const struct timeval *timeout);
     ^
In file included from ../src/redis.c:7:0:
C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\hiredis/adapters/libevent.h: In function 'redisLibeventDelWrite':
C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\hiredis/adapters/libevent.h:71:15: warning: passing argument 1 of 'event_del' from incompatible pointer type
     event_del(&e->wev);
               ^
In file included from C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\hiredis/adapters/libevent.h:33:0,
                 from ../src/redis.c:7:
C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\event2/event.h:950:5: note: expected 'struct event *' but argument is of type 'struct event **'
 int event_del(struct event *);
     ^
In file included from ../src/redis.c:7:0:
C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\hiredis/adapters/libevent.h: In function 'redisLibeventCleanup':
C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\hiredis/adapters/libevent.h:76:15: warning: passing argument 1 of 'event_del' from incompatible pointer type
     event_del(&e->rev);
               ^
In file included from C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\hiredis/adapters/libevent.h:33:0,
                 from ../src/redis.c:7:
C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\event2/event.h:950:5: note: expected 'struct event *' but argument is of type 'struct event **'
 int event_del(struct event *);
     ^
In file included from ../src/redis.c:7:0:
C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\hiredis/adapters/libevent.h:77:15: warning: passing argument 1 of 'event_del' from incompatible pointer type
     event_del(&e->wev);
               ^
In file included from C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\hiredis/adapters/libevent.h:33:0,
                 from ../src/redis.c:7:
C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\event2/event.h:950:5: note: expected 'struct event *' but argument is of type 'struct event **'
 int event_del(struct event *);
     ^
In file included from ../src/redis.c:7:0:
C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\hiredis/adapters/libevent.h: In function 'redisLibeventAttach':
C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\hiredis/adapters/libevent.h:102:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'event_set' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     event_set(&e->rev,c->fd,EV_READ,redisLibeventReadEvent,e);
     ^
C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\hiredis/adapters/libevent.h:104:25: warning: passing argument 2 of 'event_base_set' from incompatible pointer type
     event_base_set(base,&e->rev);
                         ^
In file included from C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\hiredis/adapters/libevent.h:33:0,
                 from ../src/redis.c:7:
C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\event2/event.h:627:5: note: expected 'struct event *' but argument is of type 'struct event **'
 int event_base_set(struct event_base *, struct event *);
     ^
In file included from ../src/redis.c:7:0:
C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\hiredis/adapters/libevent.h:105:25: warning: passing argument 2 of 'event_base_set' from incompatible pointer type
     event_base_set(base,&e->wev);
                         ^
In file included from C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\hiredis/adapters/libevent.h:33:0,
                 from ../src/redis.c:7:
C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\include\event2/event.h:627:5: note: expected 'struct event *' but argument is of type 'struct event **'
 int event_base_set(struct event_base *, struct event *);
     ^
'Finished building: ../src/redis.c'
' '
'Building target: redis'
'Invoking: Cross GCC Linker'
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -L"C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\usr\local\lib" -L"C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\lib" -o "redis"  ./src/redis.o   -lhiredis -levent_core -lpthread
'Finished building target: redis'
' '

00:20:55 Build Finished (took 1s.130ms)
```

Comment: It seems that the issue might be in the "adapters/libevent.h"... is it a home made adapter?

Comment: thank you! yes, problem is in this file. i load it from github again and everething is ok!

Comment: - cool  I'm happy you found it. I updated my answer for anyone wondering 

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

It seems the main issue was in the included adapter file.

The issue I pointed towards was unrelated.

---

Here is just one quick issue I noticed:

```
if (r->type == REDIS_REPLY_ARRAY) {
    for (j = 0; j < r->elements; j++) {
        printf("%u) %s\n", j, r->element[j]->str);
    }
}
```

Your code **assumes that the reply is an array of Strings**.

This is **incorrect.**

The Subscribe command also returns an Array response and the last member of that response is a NUMBER (not a string).

Hence, the assumption that it's an array of strings will fail.

I'm not sure if that's the cause, but it is likely to be an important issue.

Good Luck!

---

P.S.

I might be shamelessly promoting my own project here, but you might enjoy using [`facil.io`'s integrated Redis Pub/Sub engine](https://github.com/boazsegev/facil.io/blob/master/examples/redis_pubsub.c). If you need Websocket or HTTP support, it might save you a lot of coding.

Comment: thank you, but error exactly in using function redisAsyncCommand(). if i use empty callback function i have the same error.